# i need a solution to view uploaded photo in a data list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to view a photo in a datalist? help me to view the photos

Comment: Can you provide some more information on what are you trying to do? Is that someone is uploading the photo and you are trying to view them? How are you storing them ??

Comment: yes i want to view the uploaded it in a datalist. i am storing that in a table which contain imageid,imageurl,imagename. i want to view all the uploaded image in a datalist

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <img src="<%#Eval("ImageUrl") %>" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Provide some samples of what you've done so far, makes it easier to help...